# Cassandra CRUD Repository - Map - org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

When I use map and the Spring data CRUD Repository to insert the record getting the below exception

**Domain class**

@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.MAP,typeArguments = { DataType.Name.BIGINT,DataType.Name.TIMEUUID } )
 private Map order;

**Exception**

[org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:710), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:668), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.access$000(MappingCassandraConverter.java:89), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:343), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:338), org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:338), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromObject(MappingCassandraConverter.java:332), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:317), org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:301), org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery(CassandraTemplate.java:948), org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery(CassandraTemplate.java:717), org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:708), org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:290), org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:285), org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:60), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62), sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498), org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504), org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489), org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.MAP,typeArguments = { DataType.Name.BIGINT,DataType.Name.TIMEUUID } )
     private Map order;

Issue was resolved after reference type as Long and UUID.